# are files sent in a TLS channel signed?

Tags: encryption, tls, digital-signature

I have 2 endpoints that are exchanging data (FIX messages), and the originating endpoint is genrating the fix files are sending them on an ecrypted channel (TLS or Stunnel). In a security audit, it was recommended that the files are signed, and this is a bit confusing as the communication is in TLS mode, when reading on the TLS handshake it mentions that the exchanaged messages are signed.

**So in a nutshell, my question is: in general when files are exchaned between 2 parties using an encrypted channel, aren't the files signed by default?**

Comment: Encryption in general neither implies integrity nor signing. While TLS provides integrity in addition to encryption it does not provide signing.

Comment: OP, in addition to the questions linked above, https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/5455/does-a-trace-of-ssl-packets-provide-a-proof-of-data-authenticity is also instructive.

Answer (score 0):

No, TLS does not sign files. TLS "does not now" what is being sent, is it a file or just a part of it. Files are defined on the *application* layer, where as TLS is a *transport* layer.

For the client, TLS makes sure that the client is communicating with the expected server and not with some other server or with a man in the middle. If the client wants to establish connection to `example.com`, TLS makes sure it will be connection really to this server and not to some `attacker.com`. Thus the client is sure that any data received from server come really from the expected server.

For the server, TLS does not provide any information about the client.

Signing files can make sense, if there are corresponding threats. For instance, if you see the risk that the attacker or malicious users can modify or spoof data sent between the TLS termination point and the server application. But signing may be insufficient in such case. Encryption would be required.

Ask your auditors, what threat model they considered when they suggested you file signing.

Comment: TLS has an _option_ for client authentication, also (often) called "mutual" or "two-way" auth, but it isn't much used on the public web. It is used in some environments where  users can be trained and restricted, notably [employees of US government](https://playbooks.idmanagement.gov/piv/gettingstarted/). Perhaps relevant here, it is [supported by stunnel](https://www.stunnel.org/static/stunnel.html#requireCert-yes-no). Like (more common) server auth, it asymmetrically auths _identity_ but only symmetrically protects the data. PS: s/now/know/

Comment: @dave_thompson_085: Also mutual authentication has nothing to do with files. As I said, TLS is a *transport* layer. It does not distinguish if the data being sent are a file or not a file. The most HTTP requests are not files, but TLS does not know anything about it. Since TLS sees everything just as a stream of bytes, it is impossible to speak about *singing of files* on the TLS level.

Comment: I agree TLS doesn't sign the data, which I said ('only symmetrically protects' = MAC), and I didn't mention files at all, but your flat statement "For the server, TLS does not provide any information about the client" is false. _Often_ it doesn't, but it can, sometimes does, and could here.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085: 1) *"only symmetrically protects"* - It is a very misleading. TLS is not symmetric. Client can initiate connection server cannot. Server is authenticated, client is not (the OP does not say it is mTLS). If you mean symmetric encryption, then precise wording like *symmetric encryption* would be helpful.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085: 2) "* flat statement ... is false*" - No. The OP is about TLS, not mTLS. In TLS, client is not authenticated. Thus server has no information about who/what the client is.

Comment: Hello @dave_thompson_085,
What do you mean by s/now/know ?

Comment: mentallurg: I don't mean symmetric encryption; I mean symmetric integrity -- MAC not signature. TLS does MAC all data. 'mTLS' is just a shorthand meaning TLS with client-auth; it is not a different protocol, and is almost always included in TLS implementations -- though rarely used. OP says stunnel and stunnel definitely can do TLS with client-auth; I've used it. @ethicalhacker: the clause _TLS "does not now" what is being sent_ uses the wrong word; it should be _"does not know"_. Using Unix sed syntax to express such a minor correction is a longtime Usenet tradition.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085: You are using strange terms. 1) 
"only symmetrically protects" - Protects from what? Protects from disclosure? Protects from modification? Protects from spoofing? Protects from replay?
2) "symmetrically protects" - word "symmetrically" makes no sense in this context. Protection is mean against an attacker. If you add word "symmetrically", this would mean protection of communicating parties against attacker and protection of attackers against those who they attack. It makes no sense. Thus the expressions "symmetrically protects" makes no sense.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085: 3) "I mean symmetric integrity" - Also these words make no sense. Integrity is just integrity. It cannot be symmetric or asymmetric. 4) "MAC not signature" - Sure, nobody is talking about signature. The primary purpose of MAS is namely authentication. But you are ignoring that. 5) "definitely can do TLS" - It is common practice, that if mTLS is used, then it is mentioned explicitly. Otherwise, TLS is used in the sense that only server is authenticated, namely based on certificate.

Comment: Cryptographic algorithms are classified as symmetric or aysmmetric based on how they use keys. MACs are symmetric algorithms to protect integrity (but not authenticity). Signatures are asymmetric algorithms to protect integrity AND authenticity. TLS uses a MAC for the data but not a signature, thus the recipient can verify data is from the sender (not a MitM) but cannot prove this. Client-auth is sometimes pointed out/emphasized as 'mTLS', but it needn't be; the official definition of TLS includes it (see any/all of the RFCs -- and as I said, all or nearly all implementations).

Comment: Hello all, I have another question related, if we are not saving the files I mentioned on the server, when do we need to sign the payloads (Fix messages transformed inside TLS) ?
so in other words, we are still sending fix messages, but they are not saved on the server, they are consumed by the server directly, do we still need here to sign the fix messages? if yes or no, what is the reason ?
In my opinion and correct me if I'm wrong, signing the fix messages will be an additional layer, and not signing them would be considered fine. Please can someone confirm my conclusion ?

Comment: @ethicalhacker: Please post it as a separate question. Also explain what do you mean by "fix messages". Messages to fix what? If you mean [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Financial_Information_eXchange), the please state it clearly.

Comment: Okay, but wouldn't it be duplicate if I ask the question on another post ? it's kinda related to the question here. 
And by fix, yes I mean the protocol FIX, sorry for the inconvience .

Comment: 1) In FIX, signature is optional. It depends on specific business context. You decide, if it is needed or not. For instance, if some clients are not trusted, then signature will definitely make sense. When messages are signed, clients will not be able to say that they have not sent particular message, or that the message was modified.

Comment: 2) Yes, a news post would be partially a duplicate of the question mentioned above: [Are There Reasons to Sign Files Transported via TLS?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/164883/are-there-reasons-to-sign-files-transported-via-tls). Briefly, if you don't trust the connection between the TLS termination point and the application, signature will make unauthorized message modifications impossible.